# DataTime.format returns Feb 32 as a result

Tags: apex, datetime

I am at Australia and the time now is 13:00 Feb 1. With the following code:

```
DateTime thisTime = DateTime.now();
System.debug(thisTime);
System.debug(thisTime.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
```

For the 2nd line I got 2016-01-01 03:22:04 which is correct. But for the 3rd line(the format one) I got 32/02/2016 + time. Is that a Salesforce bug? Any known issues or walkarounds?

Comment: I can't follow your example. Today is feb 2nd, but you say 01-01 is correct? Can you include the exact debug outputs, just to be sure?

Comment: @Guy Sorry, typo, it should be 01-02

Answer (score 6):

My fault. It should be dd/MM/YYYY instead of DD/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 6):

But did you figure out what D (Capital D) mean?

Here is your answer

[image]

For more details

https://paulforce.wordpress.com/2009/08/27/formatting-time-in-apex/

Comment: Here is a even better list provided in Salesforce doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html